# Estimating the Size of Binary Data encoded as a B64 String in Python

Tags: python, string, binary

So I have some Binary data in python (a jpg Image, in this case) that I am retreiving from an API as a B64 encoded string. Is there an easy way to estimate the size of this (image) file on the disk?

```
<Image>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/4RriRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABwESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAAUA
AAABAAAAYgEbAAUAAAABAAAAagEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAIAAAAeAAAAcgEyAAIAAAAUAAAAkIdp
AAQAAAABAAAApAAAANAACvyAAAAnEAAK/IAAACcQQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9z ....... </Image>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can multiply the length of the string by 3/4 to get the size in bytes.

```
(len(str) * 3) / 4
```

Comment: isn't Base64 larger than the actual size in bytes? I always thought that size of B64 > Size in Bytes, whereas in this case it would be the opposite

Comment: As a follow up question, is the size of the Base64 string itself == the length of the string? I know that its true for 8bit strings, which are the default string encoding in python

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this:

```
def size(b64string):
    return (len(b64string) * 3) / 4 - b64string.count('=', -2)
```

We remove the length of the padding, which is either no, one or two characters `=`, as [explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding).

Probably not optimal. I don't how efficient `str.count(char)` is. On the other hand, it is only performed on a string of length 2.