# How can I compute the size in bits of group elements in charm-crypto?

Tags: signature

I want to use the scheme [“Hess - Efficient identity based signature schemes based on pairings.”](https://jhuisi.github.io/charm/charm/schemes/pksig/pksig_hess.html) of [Charm-Crypto](https://jhuisi.github.io/charm/index.html).

I need to calculate the bit-length of group elements (eg. S2 in the siganture).

As I understand it from [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535939/bit-length-of-key-in-charm-crypto), serializing the elements gives me a Base64 encoded string. From that and [this other question about Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793575/estimating-the-size-of-binary-data-encoded-as-a-b64-string-in-python), I concluded that I need to compute the following:

```
signature = {'S1' : S1, 'S2' : S2}
S2_serial = group.serialize(signature['S2'])

sigLenInBase64 = len(S2_serial)
sigLenInByte = (sigLenInBase64 *3)/4
sigLenInBit = sigLenInByte * 8
```

As S2 is a group element of G1, I expect the size to be the same as that of the underlying curve (so 512Bit for 'SS512', 224Bit for 'MNT224', etc). However, the size differ by 28 Bit  for 'SS512' and 'MNT224' (with 540 and 252 Bit, respectively) and by 21 Bit for 'MNT159'. Why is that? How can I predict for a given curve by how much it will be off?

My current guess is, that I'm not taking into account some additional info (like a byte for the sign).

Update:
Using the accepted answer, I now can correctly compute the size like this:

```
def compute_bitsize(base64_input):
    b_padded = base64_input.split(str.encode(":"))[1]
    pad_size = b_padded.count(str.encode("="))
    b_len_without_pad = len(b_padded)-4
    byte_len = (b_len_without_pad *3)/4 +(3-pad_size)-1
    bit_len = byte_len * 8
    return bit_len
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the example serialization for 'SS512' from the [question you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535939/bit-length-of-key-in-charm-crypto). The serialization string is:

> 1:Nri028S0SySkDoN0JH1Lu6HQo/Jkhq7DCZHI1MUrHOuIgCONonN14GzmhwopYQOxnjOysclhYNOnsvCLjVDLggE=

Looking at the line:

> PyObject *result = PyBytes_FromFormat("%d:%s", element->element_type, (const char *) base64_data_buf);

from [the source code for charm](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm/blob/dev/charm/core/math/pairing/pairingmodule.c) we see that the part of the string you are interested in is

> Nri028S0SySkDoN0JH1Lu6HQo/Jkhq7DCZHI1MUrHOuIgCONonN14GzmhwopYQOxnjOysclhYNOnsvCLjVDLggE=

Decoding this as described on [Wikipedia under 'Decoding Base64 with padding'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding) gives us 65 bytes where one byte is a "byte for the sign of the element" according to the [question you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535939/bit-length-of-key-in-charm-crypto).